# How to add reference for OData v4 endpoint using asp.net web api 2.2 to mvc client application

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I am new to web api. I have created an OData v4 endpoint using asp.net web API 2.2 using VS 2013. I have followed this article http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint. It's working perfect. (tried through fiddler also)

Service side:-------------------------------------------------------------------

```
{
  "@odata.context":"http://localhost:57549/odata/$metadata","value":[
    {
      "name":"Courses","kind":"EntitySet","url":"Courses"
    },{
      "name":"Departments","kind":"EntitySet","url":"Departments"
    }
  ]
}
```

Client side:--------------------------------------------------------------------

Now I have MVC client application (in VS 2012) to which I want to add service reference for my OData v4 Endpoint. I have tried using add service reference but it throws following error (I have followed this article: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v3/calling-an-odata-service-from-a-net-client):

```
There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:57549/odata/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:57549/odata'.
The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed.
The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

I am not sure how to add web api2.2 reference to MVC client application. How to resolve above error? Is that possible to add Odata endpoint (using asp.net web api 2.2) through Add Service Reference?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to add reference to OData V4 service, you should use the [OData V4 Client Code Generator](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9b786c0e-79d1-4a50-89a5-125e57475937) instead of Add Service Reference as the latter one only supports OData V1-3.

The proxy generated from both tools are very similar. The team has invested a lot in keeping API consistency.

Following are a few tutorials for you to quickly ramp up the tool:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2014/03/12/how-to-use-odata-client-code-generator-to-generate-client-side-proxy-class.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2014/07/09/odata-client-code-generator-2-0-0-release.aspx

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-client-app